# Multi-threading functions in Computer Craft

Tags: lua, computercraft

I'm working on a project where I want to update the clock on screen say every 5 seconds unless the user inputs something. This is the code I have so far,

```
function thread1()
  term.clear()
  term.setCursorPos(1,1)
  write (" SteveCell        ")
  local time = os.time()
  local formatTime = textutils.formatTime(time, false)
  write (formatTime)
  print ("")
  print ("")
  for i=1,13 do
    write ("-")
  end
  print("")
  print ("1. Clock")
  print ("2. Calender")
  print ("3. Memo")
  print ("4. Shutdown")
  for i=1,13 do
    write ("-")
  end
  print ("")
  print ("")
  write ("Choose an option: ")
  local choice = io.read()
  local choiceValid = false
  if (choice == "1") then
    -- do this
  elseif (choice == "2") then
    -- do that
  elseif (choice == "3") then
    -- do this
  elseif (choice == "4") then
    shell.run("shutdown")
  else
    print ("Choice Invalid")
    os.sleep(2)
    shell.run("mainMenu")
  end
end

function thread2()
  localmyTimer = os.startTimer(5)
  while true do
    local event,timerID = os.pullEvent("timer")
    if timerID == myTimer then break end
  end
  return
end

parallel.waitForAny(thread1, thread2)
shell.run("mainMenu")
```

Unfortunately it's not working. If someone could help me with this, I would really appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this (Im not doing the correct on screen drawing, only the time)

```
local function thread1_2()
   -- both threads in one!

   while true do
      local ID_MAIN = os.startTimer(5)
      local ID = os.startTimer(0.05)
      local e = { os.pullEvent() }
      if e[1] == "char" then
         -- Check all the options with variable e[2] here
         print( string.format( "Pressed %s", e[2] ) )
         break -- Getting out of the 'thread'
      elseif e[1] == "timer" and e[2] == ID then
         ID = os.startTimer(0.05) -- shortest interval in cc
         redrawTime() -- Redraw and update the time in this function!!!
      elseif e[1] == "timer" and e[2] == MAIN_ID then
         break
      end
   end
end
```

Also, ask this in the proper [forum](http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/forum/14-ask-a-pro/), you have more chance getting an answer there!
Another note, get more into event handling, it really helps.

Answer (score 0):

FYI Lua doesn't have 'multi-threading' as in executing multiple routines simultaneously. What it does have is 'thread parking.' You can switch between routines (yielding) and switch back and it will resume where it left off, but only a single routine will be active at any given time.

This is my go-to Lua reference, which explains in detail:
http://lua-users.org/wiki/CoroutinesTutorial